# Gigabit router only using 100mbit

Tags: networking, router, switch, internet-speed

I have the following configuration:

a 100mbit router connected to a gigabit router(TP-Link WR1043ND) in a LAN port (WAN ports are empty). DHCP is disabled on the gigabit router so it is just making a wireless network (300mbit) and is working as switch.

I'm testing with my local network behind the gigabit router. I have my desktop connected directly via a cable, and a second desktop connected via a gigabit switch which is verified to work at 1gigabit.
I would expect data transfers to be higher than 100mbit, but the transfers are capped at 100mbit. I also checked this with a tool called LANBench.

So then I wondered probably the 100 mbit router. So I removed the connection from the 100mbit router, enabled DHCP in the gigabit router, and tested again. Still capped :(

[image]

Is there a reason why the speed is limited, where can this be?

Comment: Do the network interfaces of the devices you connect to the router negotiate 1000Mbit connections?

Comment: @Paul Yes, both pc's are gaming systems with gigabit internet interfaces and SSD disks, so there should be no problem

Comment: "making a wireless network (300mbit)" What do you mean a wireless network? Are you using Ethernet or wireless?

Comment: In this test case I am only using ethernet.

Comment: I added a picture. Can you verify that it is correct? Also, WAN ports? Multiple?

Comment: This is correct, I tested with the green cable going in a LAN port of the router.

Comment: Both PCs connect at Gbit speed, but there is a third connection (the one in yellow between the TP and the nameless Gbit switch). Does that one sync at gbit speed?

Comment: I can not think of a reason why not... But I have no idea how to test that...

Comment: No LEDs on the switch to indicate link speed?  Also, not a proper test, but what happens if you connect a laptop (or PC2) directly to the yellow cable. If the cable is cat 3 (not good enough for gbit speeds) then it should negotiate at lower speeds.

Comment: @2pietjuh2, did you try connecting second desktop directly to the router using yellow cable alone, and then orange cable?

Comment: Are the two desktop's using IP addresses in the same subnet? Can you check the ports to see if the link between the switch and the WR1043MD is running at Gigabit speeds. I'd suspect that cable is not gigabit capable.

Comment: After some more debugging I found that the orange cable limited the speed. I changed that cable and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

If you removed the 100mbps router, then it is irrelevant (as is the fact that it's a "gaming system").

Check that the connection is truly being negotiated at 1.0 Gbps:
[image]

Assuming you're running Windows 7, you can find this by typing "View network connections" in the Start Menu, clicking `View Network Connections`, and double clicking the appropriate network interface.

You might want to check your cables. If you're not seeing 1.0 Gbps, I'd double check your NIC drivers and your cables, and try rebooting your router.

Comment: I am seeing 1.0Gbps, on both pc's. That's why I am confused